# Rails using wrong action, search parameters appended to current URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing

I have a search box in a navbar that should display the search results on the designated page /listings/search. But for some reason, the search parameters are appended to the current URL, not the one that I specified in the code.

This means that I often do not get the search results returned, just the current page.

Form code:

```
<%= simple_form_for :search, url: search_listings_path, method: :get do |f| %>
  <div class='input-group'>
    <%= f.input :address, label_html: { class: 'sr-only' }, label: 'Address', id: 'search_address', placeholder: 'Search', input_html: { value: session[:address] }, required: false %>

    <span class='input-group-btn'>
      <button class='btn btn-primary' type='submit' aria-hidden='true' aria-label='Search'><i class='fa fa-search'></i></button>
    </span>
  </div>

  <%= render '/listings/address_autocomplete' %>
<% end %>
```

This code generates the following HTML:

```
<form novalidate="novalidate" class="simple_form search" action="/listings/search" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="get"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" />
  <div class='input-group'>
    <div class="form-group string optional search_address"><label class="string optional sr-only control-label" for="search_address">Address</label><input value="London, United Kingdom" class="string optional form-control" placeholder="Search" type="text" name="search[address]" id="search_address" /></div>

    <span class='input-group-btn'>
      <button class='btn btn-primary' type='submit' aria-hidden='true' aria-label='Search'><i class='fa fa-search'></i></button>
    </span>
  </div>

<script type='text/javascript'>
  function initialize() {
    var input = document.getElementById('search_address');

    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
  }

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>

</form>
```

The action `/listings/search` is correct.

But Rails appends the search parameters to the current URL. Sample output:

```
Started GET "/listings/13?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search%5Baddress%5D=London%2C+United+Kingdom" for ::1 at 2015-08-29 19:19:17 +0100
Processing by ListingsController#show as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "search"=>{"address"=>"London, United Kingdom"}, "id"=>"13"}
```

Rails uses `show` rather than `search`.

Expected URL:

```
http://localhost:3000/listings/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search%5Baddress%5D=London%2C+United+Kingdom
```

Actual URL:

```
http://localhost:3000/listings/13?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search%5Baddress%5D=London%2C+United+Kingdom
```

The relevant portion of routes.rb:

```
resources :listings do
  collection do
    get 'search'
  end

  resources :orders, only: [:new, :create]
end
```

The relevant portion of `rake routes`:

```
search_listings GET    /listings/search(.:format)                 listings#search
```

Any ideas on what the issue might be?

Controller code for `listings#search`:

```
def search
  # persist address search parameter 
  session[:address] = params[:search][:address].presence || ""

  # define initial set of listings with no filters applied
  @listings = Listing.all.order('created_at DESC')

  # restrict to 100-km radius and sort by distance if address entered
  if params[:search][:address].present?
    @listings = Listing.all.near(params[:search][:address], 100, units: :km, order: 'distance')
  end

  # filter by price
  if params[:search][:price_lower].present? || params[:search][:price_upper].present?
    @listings = @listings.where('price >= ? AND price <= ?', params[:search][:price_lower], params[:search][:price_upper])
  end

  # filter by size
  if params[:search][:size_lower].present? || params[:search][:size_upper].present?
    @listings = @listings.where('size >= ? AND size <= ?', params[:search][:size_lower], params[:search][:size_upper])
  end

  # filter by space type
  if params[:search][:space_ids].nil? || params[:search][:space_ids].size <= 1
    @listings = @listings.group(:id)
  else
    @listings = @listings.joins(:spaces).where('space_id IN (?)', params[:search][:space_ids].reject!(&:blank?))
  end

  # filter by amenities
  if params[:search][:amenity_ids].nil? || params[:search][:amenity_ids].size <= 1
    @listings = @listings.group(:id)
  else
    @listings = @listings.joins(:amenities).where(:amenities => { :id => params[:search][:amenity_ids].reject!(&:blank?) }).group(:id).having('count(*) = ?', params[:search][:amenity_ids].size)
  end

  @hash = Gmaps4rails.build_markers(@listings) do |listing, marker|
    marker.lat listing.latitude
    marker.lng listing.longitude
    marker.infowindow listing.address
    marker.json({ :id => listing.id })
    marker.infowindow render_to_string(:partial => '/listings/map_infowindow', :locals => { :listing => listing })
  end
end
```

(I will refactor once everything works properly.)

Comment: Are there any before_action filters involved in `search`? Can you show us all relevant controller code for `listings#search`?

Comment: I added the controller code to my original post. Just a bunch of filters that I will refactor once I get everything working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue. The problem is caused by the Bootstrap form class code surrounding my search box partial:

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
  ...
</form>
```

Deleting the form class code fixes the issue, and the search box works as expected.

However, this leaves me with a search box too large for the navbar, and now I need to find the appropriate class to make it fit and position it properly.

Thanks, everyone.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think it's related with your routes and controllers -- everything looks right. If you call directly your expected URL, the result is OK, right?

Can you show more of your HTML generated? There is some other form in page? Some javascript binding something else? From where come this id 13 (it could help)?

Comment: Yes, if I load the expected URL directly, the result is perfect. And everything does look right. The id 13 is the listing id. If I navigate to another page, say, the page showing the listing with id 13, and then try to search using the search box in the navbar, I remain on the show page.

I also tried disabling javascript, but that did not help.

There is some javascript for other things, e.g., image carousel, calendar, map, but nothing related to this. Is there anything in the HTML that would be of interest?